# How do i call the controller from a new folder in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How do i call a controller from anchor tag when Controller is on the:

Area->Ticket->TicketController

Here is the code:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("TicketTemplate", "MyTickets", new {area = string.Empty,controller = "TicketTemplate", page = Model.PageNumber, sort = "DateCreated ", isAsc = isAsc })">
                        Date Created
                        <span class="@clsDateCreated" style="text-align: right;"></span>
                    </a>
```

The above code is not working..
How do i call the controller??
Here is the path:

```
~/Areas/Ticket/Controllers/TicketTemplateController.cs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that and it will work, but i don't know if there is a better solution or not.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("MyTickets", "Ticket/TicketTemplate", , new {area = string.Empty,controller = "TicketTemplate", page = Model.PageNumber, sort = "DateCreated ", isAsc = isAsc })">
    Date Created
   <span class="@clsDateCreated" style="text-align: right;"></span>
</a>
```